# Moving a graphic Tshirt from clo3D to blender

Tags: objects

I have designed an oversized graphic tshirt in clo3D[image], but when I try to Export it as an OBJ/gITF into blender the graphic seems to not load.[image] sometimes I might get just the tshirt with a weird black design like there is no texture, or tshirt at all. I have ticked and unticked almost all boxes in the export menu in clothing 3D[image], I have tried baking the graphic into the design and followed almost all tutorials step by step and yet still somehow my graphics never seem to work. I have heard of an application called connecter but that is only on windows, im using an m1 MacBook. can someone with experience in both clothing 3d and blender pls help im losing my mind.

Comment: I don't think that you can export Obj with image textures, so you need to prepare a material in Blender and import your image

Comment: Please don't upload images taken with your phone! Use Blender's built-in Window > Save Screenshot menu which eliminates any artifacts and moire patterns that you get when taking a picture of your monitor screen.   You'll have to ask about your other application elsewhere. We can only help with questions about Blender itself here.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures